# Upgrading OS X frees disk space -- why?

Tags: macos, upgrade, disk-space

I noticed that every time I upgrade OS X to a newer version, a significant amount of disk space (10-20 GB) is freed up.  This applies both to minor (10.9.4 -> 10.9.5) and major (10.9 -> 10.10) upgrades.  When upgrading to Yosemite, no less than 27 GB was freed.

What exactly gets deleted that returns all this space, and how can I free up (or control) this supposedly unneeded space when not doing an upgrade?

Comment: You are checking free space **prior** to beginning the download for an update, versus free space after installation, correct?

Comment: Thats quite a substantial amount.  You should run Disk Inventory X or WhatSize next time and screenshot before and after.

Comment: It's normal to free ~5GB (the size of the installer) but 27GB is a lot.

Comment: @tubedogg Yes, that's right.  I cleaned up in preparation for the installation to make sure I'd have enough free space.  After the cleanup I had 18 GB.  Then I started the download.  When the installation finished, I had 45 GB.  This happens every single time I upgrade the OS, though it was never this extreme before.  I have local time machine backups disabled.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is logs and temporary files that might accumulate between updates, but there should be nothing that would account for 27GB. Even 10GB seems way too high.